# How to add element to Bootstrap Dropdown list item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a div to each item in a Dropdown, however the item looses the bootstrap styling.

CSS

```
.ul.dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Example 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <div>
                <a>Item One</a>
                <div>
                    <i class="material-icons " style="font-size:18px">more_horiz</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I've created examples of the dropdown before and after the additional element to demonstrate the issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Rob_H/nqu621vm/

Comment: Why do you need a div here? Just to add the icon? if so you can do it within `a` tag itself

Comment: I've put the icon in a div because I want to add some styling to that area on hover etc.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Rob_H/nqu621vm/3/ (Example 2) using the answer from @Ahmer. I've also added some more styling to align the list item and allow for text overflow. This works now, however I'm not a pro dev so I'm not sure if it's best practice or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For continue same style they need a tag as root otherwise you can enhance css

```
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Example 2
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
      <a>
       <div>
         Item One
         <div>
          <i class="material-icons " style="font-size:18px">more_horiz</i>
          </div>
          </div></a>  
        </li>

         <li>
         <a>
       <div>
         Item One
         <div>
          <i class="material-icons " style="font-size:18px">more_horiz</i>
          </div>
          </div></a>  
        </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because bootstrap has a styles for `.dropdown-menu>li>a` but not for `.dropdown-menu>li>div` so you have to copy the needed styles from bootstrap `dropdown` and customize it for your needs.

Check the updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqu621vm/2/).

Hope this helps.